# F2 to rename file open terminal

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, rename

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome-shell 3.2, and i may have done something wrong (probably with dconf or gconf).

But now pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> within nautilus opens a terminal, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> do the rename stuff (but selecting all filename including extension).

How can I can revert back to default behavior ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Under the "System Settings application **>** Keyboard **>** Shortcuts **>** Launchers" you can set the shortcut to launch Terminal. I guess there is your problem!

[image]

This would be my second guess in **gconf**!

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no, this one is set to F4 (by myself) and works fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are welcome pled! I edited my post with a second possible solution. Hopefully this does the trick for you?!

Comment: The answer is still No :-( The "run_command_terminal" key is set to F4 here as well. Actually, I think it is related to the setting related to the "rename default behaviour (F2)" which is stored somewhere in dconf or gconf. I know I have been modifying such key, but cannot remember where it is. Thanks again for helping !

Comment: I also looked within "dconf", but couldn't find something useful there. Maybe "GConf Cleaner" which is available through the Ubuntu Software Center can restore the old key-shortcuts, though i haven't tried it! Good LucK!!

Comment: I tried GConf-cleaner without success. I ended backuping then deleting ~/.config/dconf/user, and it worked. F2 is back ! it is not a big work now to personalize it again, so all is fine. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome and glad to read, that you succeeded pled!